# Why are showing blank page in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using class and constructor in react-js but this program does not error is thrown
in console. show a message only blank. what is wrong?

```
class Strick_ extends React. Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { color: "red" };
      }
      render() {
        
        return <h1> this color {this.state.color} </h1>;
      }
    }
    ReactDom.render(Strick_, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass it as `<Component />`. And Still doesn't work then add your `index.html`, there might be the issue then.

```
class Strick_ extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { color: "red" };
      }
      render() {
        
        return <h1> this color {this.state.color} </h1>;
      }
    }

// you need to pass as element component <Component/>
ReactDom.render(<Strick_/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**PS:** If you want to render only element *only html element* then you can do as you did and same is mentioned in [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper). And you should return element from Component [[Ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#elements)].

Comment: OK how can use this code in element in class?                                                               
 class Strick_ extends React.Component
{
render(){
  return
}
}
const renders = <h2>hum do humre do </h2>
const root = ReactDom.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(renders);

Comment: By basic element I meant only `element=<h2>hum do humare do </h2>` . You can go through docs it also mentions the same.

Comment: How can two class use ? this is my code and output blank screening showing. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-galois-uosrml?file=/src/index.js:4205-4564

Comment: In the following sandbox. Code is commented and code which is not commented is working totally fine. You cannot render two Component in same html element.

Comment: Ok thank you resovle problem

Comment: For the next question , I want to click button and then value change but value not change this link below https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-resonance-8v8h0o?file=/src/index.js

Comment: It's better to keep this question to one issue only for next issue please create other question.

Comment: Ok but stackoverflow not allowed questions saying that after 5 day will be post..

Answer (score -1):

I suppose the issue is the space between `React.` and `Component`.

Comment: try `[1,2,3].    map(e=>e)` you will get the result. It does not matter.

Comment: Just tried but the same problem still.